# Not able to view Scaling options for Virtual Machine Scale Sets

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-vm-scale-set

I am not able to view the Scaling options in a Virtual Machine Scale Set I had created.

There are 3 workers configured on a VMSS and I would like to scale up and down based on a Storage Queue Size. However I am not able to see the Scaling and many other options on the blade.

The worker instances are configured with an Ubuntu image.

This is the screen on the docs found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-autoscale-portal)
[image: VMSSDocImage]

This is what I have on my VMSS blade:
[image: MyVMSSBlade]

I would really appreciate the help!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens you select the **VirtualMachine** as [Orchestration modes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/orchestration-modes#orchestration-modes) when you create a virtual machine scale set.

[image]

See the comparison below. In this case, you could select the **ScaleSetVM** Orchestration modes if you want to automatically scale or manually scale.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply. When I create a VMSS first and create the VMs through that, I was able to solve this.
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Did you click enable autoscale? when you do that you should be able to see a screen to do the configuration as follows

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was not even able to see the Scaling option on the left. When I created the VMSS on its own and created VMs from it, I can see see those options :)
Cheers!